# get php api array and instert into flutter table

Tags: php, arrays, flutter, dart

I want to return an api responds and make a for each statement .....

The api is

```
$user = "";
$ssn = '';

$return["message"] = "";
$return["success"] = false;
$post_ref = "";
$error = "";
$array =[];

if ($error == "") {
    $obj = viewRequest($ssn, $post_ref);
    //print_r($obj);
    if ($obj == null) {
        // $error = "API ERROR";
        $error = "Service is currently unavailable - We could not process your request. <br> We are bussy attending to this issue.";
    
    }
    if ($error == "" AND $obj['goodStanding'] == null) {
        // $error = "API GoodStanding ARRAY NULL";
        $error = "No Goodstanding request records found.";
    }
    //print_r($obj);
    $array = $obj['goodStanding'];

    if ($error == "" AND $array == null) {
        // $error = "API GoodStanding JSON ARRAY NOT FOUND";
        $error = "No Goodstanding request records found.";
   
        if ($error == "") {

            $usort = usort($array, function ($item1, $item2) {
                return $item2['goods_ref'] <=> $item1['goods_ref'];
            });
            $return["success"] = true;

            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $goods_ref = $value['goods_ref'];
                $bn_code = $value['bn_code'];
                $req_status = $value['req_status'];
                $status = requestStatus($req_status);
                $req_date = substr($value['req_date'], 0, 10);
                $comment = $value['comments'];
            }
        }
        ///require_once 'layout_footer.php';
    }

    // print_r($array);
    } else {
        $error = "No Employer found";
    }
    // echo $error;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
```

The above code is the php api that returns this value

```
{
    "$id":"6",
    "goods_ref":60,
    "loyer":"",
    "bn_code":"",
    "loyee_no":1,
    "contact_name":null,
    "contact_tel":null,
    "bn_desc":"DEVELOP PAYROLL HR SYSTEMS",
    "req_status":"N",
    "e_mail":null,
    "comments":"",
    "tender":[
        {"$id":"7",
        "goods_ref":0,
        "in_no":1,
        "tender_no":"GENERAL",
        "closing_date":""
        },{
        "$id":"8",
        "goods_ref":0,
        "in_no":2,
        "tender_no":"GENERAL",
        "closing_date":""
        }
    ],
    "req_date":"2020-02-20T00:00:00",
    "ssc_office":null
},{
    "$id":"9",
    "goods_ref":763800,
    "loyer":"",
    "bn_code":"00143379",
    "loyee_no":1,
"contact_name":null,"contact_tel":null,"bn_desc":"DEVELOP PAYROLL HR SYSTEMS","req_status":"N","e_mail":null,"comments":"APRIL 2020 TO DATE,W\/R ","tender":[{"$id":"10","goods_ref":0,"in_no":1,"tender_no":"Bg\/245","closing_date":"9\/30\/2021 12:00:00 AM"}],"req_date":"2021-09-28T00:00:00","ssc_office":null},{"$id":"11","goods_ref":774369,"loyer":"","bn_code":"","loyee_no":1,"contact_name":null,"contact_tel":null,"bn_desc":"DEVELOP PAYROLL HR SYSTEMS","req_status":"N","e_mail":null,"comments":"msd+wr outstanding for19&20 ","tender":[{"$id":"12","goods_ref":0,"in_no":1,"tender_no":"General","closing_date":"11\/25\/2021 12:00:00 AM"}],"req_date":"2021-11-01T00:00:00","ssc_office":null},{"$id":"13","goods_ref":774719,"loyer":"","bn_code":"","loyee_no":1,"contact_name":null,"contact_tel":null,"bn_desc":"DEVELOP PAYROLL HR SYSTEMS","req_status":"N","e_mail":null,"comments":"WR+MSD ","tender":[{"$id":"14","goods_ref":0,"in_no":1,"tender_no":"General","closing_date":"11\/11\/2021 12:00:00 AM"}],"req_date":"2021-11-02T00:00:00","ssc_office":null}
```

So i am calling this api through flutter using

```
goodstanding() async {
    String apiurl = "";
    //dont use http://localhost , because emulator don't get that address
    //insted use your local IP address or use live URL
    //hit "ipconfig" in windows or "ip a" in linux to get you local IP

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiurl), body: {
      'username': email //get the username text

    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);
            if (jsondata["error"]) {
                setState(() {
                    showprogress = false; //don't show progress indicator
                    error = true;
                    errormsg = jsondata["success"];
                });
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: "Invalid Login Attempt",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: colorCurve,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0
                );
            } else {
                if (jsondata["success"] ) {
                    setState(() {
                        error = false;
                        showprogress = false;
                    });
                    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    
                    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    
                        premiumList
                          ..add(Property(propertyName:"Company: $data") );
                        //save the data returned from server
                        //and navigate to home page
                        // premiumList
                        //   ..add("Company : $me3");
                        //user shared preference to save data
                    }
                }else {
                    showprogress = false; //don't show progress indicator
                    error = true;
                    errormsg = "Something went wrong.";
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "Something went wrong",
                          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.0
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            setState(() {
                showprogress = false; //don't show progress indicator
                error = true;
                errormsg = "Error during connecting to server.";
            });
        }
    }
```

I would like to print in in the widget the prints the table that is below

```
 Card upperBoxCard1() {
    return Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: size.getWidthPx(10), vertical: size.getWidthPx(20)),
        borderOnForeground: true,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: colorCurve2,
                width: 3,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13))
          ),


          height: size.getWidthPx(224),
          child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
            Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Motlee Payroll Systems CC',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: colorCurve2),
                )),
            DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text(
                    'Request ID',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                )),
                DataColumn(label: Text(
                    'Status',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                )),
                DataColumn(label: Text(
                    'Date',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                )),
              ],


              rows: [
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('1125')),
                  DataCell(Text('Pending')),
                  DataCell(Text('WR')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('1125')),
                  DataCell(Text('Pending')),
                  DataCell(Text('WR')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('1125')),
                  DataCell(Text('Print')),
                  DataCell(Text('')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('1125')),
                  DataCell(Text('Pending')),
                  DataCell(Text('WR')),
                ]),
              ],
            ),
          ])


          ),
        );
  }
```

How do I go about inserting the array into the table so that every row in array prints in a new data cell row

the aim is below . if user selects the company the company data should reflect on table

[image]

Comment: _If you can read it, theres a chance you can fix it!_ Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you , I just joined this year and am new

Answer (score 0):

> First Create Model class for getting response

```
class Model {
Model({
    this.id,
    this.goodsRef,
    this.loyer,
    this.bnCode,
    this.loyeeNo,
    this.contactName,
    this.contactTel,
    this.bnDesc,
    this.reqStatus,
    this.eMail,
    this.comments,
    this.tender,
    this.reqDate,
    this.sscOffice,
});

final String id;
final int goodsRef;
final String loyer;
final String bnCode;
final int loyeeNo;
final dynamic contactName;
final dynamic contactTel;
final String bnDesc;
final String reqStatus;
final dynamic eMail;
final String comments;
final List<Tender> tender;
final DateTime reqDate;
final dynamic sscOffice;

factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
    id: json["\u0024id"] == null ? null : json["\u0024id"],
    goodsRef: json["goods_ref"] == null ? null : json["goods_ref"],
    loyer: json["loyer"] == null ? null : json["loyer"],
    bnCode: json["bn_code"] == null ? null : json["bn_code"],
    loyeeNo: json["loyee_no"] == null ? null : json["loyee_no"],
    contactName: json["contact_name"],
    contactTel: json["contact_tel"],
    bnDesc: json["bn_desc"] == null ? null : json["bn_desc"],
    reqStatus: json["req_status"] == null ? null : json["req_status"],
    eMail: json["e_mail"],
    comments: json["comments"] == null ? null : json["comments"],
    tender: json["tender"] == null ? null : List<Tender>.from(json["tender"].map((x) => Tender.fromJson(x))),
    reqDate: json["req_date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["req_date"]),
    sscOffice: json["ssc_office"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "\u0024id": id == null ? null : id,
    "goods_ref": goodsRef == null ? null : goodsRef,
    "loyer": loyer == null ? null : loyer,
    "bn_code": bnCode == null ? null : bnCode,
    "loyee_no": loyeeNo == null ? null : loyeeNo,
    "contact_name": contactName,
    "contact_tel": contactTel,
    "bn_desc": bnDesc == null ? null : bnDesc,
    "req_status": reqStatus == null ? null : reqStatus,
    "e_mail": eMail,
    "comments": comments == null ? null : comments,
    "tender": tender == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(tender.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "req_date": reqDate == null ? null : reqDate.toIso8601String(),
    "ssc_office": sscOffice,
};
    }

 class Tender {
  Tender({
    this.id,
    this.goodsRef,
    this.inNo,
    this.tenderNo,
    this.closingDate,
});

final String id;
final int goodsRef;
final int inNo;
final String tenderNo;
final String closingDate;

factory Tender.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tender(
    id: json["\u0024id"] == null ? null : json["\u0024id"],
    goodsRef: json["goods_ref"] == null ? null : json["goods_ref"],
    inNo: json["in_no"] == null ? null : json["in_no"],
    tenderNo: json["tender_no"] == null ? null : json["tender_no"],
    closingDate: json["closing_date"] == null ? null : json["closing_date"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "\u0024id": id == null ? null : id,
    "goods_ref": goodsRef == null ? null : goodsRef,
    "in_no": inNo == null ? null : inNo,
    "tender_no": tenderNo == null ? null : tenderNo,
    "closing_date": closingDate == null ? null : closingDate,
};}
```

> then use fetch function just like that

```
fetch() async {
String apiurl = "";
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiurl), body: {
  'username': email //get the username text
});

if(response.statusCode==200) //as wish wish check your response
{
   List<Model> model =  jsonDecode(response.body).map((item) => item).toList();
     return model
   }

    }
```

Comment: any idea how one would implement it in the  Card upperBoxCard1() widget for the table ....problem is I'm struggling with the for each flutter statement for the cells in table to be done